# How to make p consective characters by making k swaps in a String?

Tags: arrays, string, algorithm

There is a String of `1's` and `0's` for example `110001110`. I have given two numbers `k` and `p` and I have to check whether I can get atmost `p` consecutive `1's` or `0's` by doing `k` swaps and by swaps I mean if it is `1` then make it `0` and vice versa.

EDIT- I think I have not clearly explained.
For example let the string be `1110000111` and let `p = 3` and `k = 1`. So can I by doing 1 swaps get atmost 3 consective `1's` or `0's` for which the answer is `yes` since I can change it into `1110010111`.

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: Are you allowed to make 0 swaps? Even if `k > 0`.

Comment: It's good you try competitive programming. Now, try solving it on your own instead of cheating. (This question is from [ongoing online competition](https://www.codechef.com/MARCH17/problems/SCHEDULE))

Comment: @amit Yes sir I know it is from an online coding contest and I have already submitted the correct solution prior asking this question.
Actually my solution was O(nlogn) and somewhat with hook or crook. I wanted to know a better way and tbh tutorials never help.

cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this in linear time with a straightforward loop. After detecting a monotonous sequence of either all 0 or all 1, you would calculate how many flips would be necessary with a simple formula. These flips can always be made in such a way that the outer digits of that sequence will remain untouched, except for the case where **p** is 1. In that case the flips must be made to either get 01010101... or else 101010101.... Also that can be done with a simple modulo expression. The best of the two would then be taken (fewer swaps).

Here is an implementation in JavaScript with two sample runs for the generic case (p > 1) and the mentioned special case (p = 1):

```js
function swapsForMaxSequence(s, maxSize) {
    var head, tail, swaps;

    if (maxSize < 1) return false;
    
    swaps = 0;
    if (maxSize === 1) { // Special case
        // 0 and 1 should be alternating:
        for (head = 0; head < s.length; head++) { // n iterations
            if (Number(s[head]) == head % 2) swaps++;
        }
        // Either the made swaps or the opposite swaps would do it:
        return Math.min(swaps, s.length - swaps);
    }
    tail = 0;
    for (head = 1; head <= s.length; head++) { // n iterations
        if (head === s.length || s[head] != s[tail]) { // end of sequence?
            swaps += Math.floor((head - tail)/(maxSize+1));
            tail = head; // Start of new sequence
        }
    }
    return swaps;
}

// Sample input:
var s = '10110101010', // Special case
    k = 1,
    p = 1;

// Display input:
console.log('s:', s, 'k:', k, 'p:', p);

// Run the algorithm
result = swapsForMaxSequence(s, p);

// Display outcome:
console.log('result:', result);

// Second sample:
var s = '1110000111', // Special case
    k = 1,
    p = 3;

// Display input:
console.log('s:', s, 'k:', k, 'p:', p);

// Run the algorithm
result = swapsForMaxSequence(s, p);

// Display outcome:
console.log('result:', result);
```

Comment: I am sorry for incomplete information in the question. I have edited it.

Comment: I rewrote my answer in light of that clarification.

Comment: Heads up, this question is from [ongoing online competition](https://www.codechef.com/MARCH17/problems/SCHEDULE). Please, avoid helping the OP get unfair advantage over other participants.

Comment: @trincot Thanks a lot sir!
Your logic is far better than mine and the code is 1/3 of what I wrote.